# What is the best way to query a bunch of cols with a covering index if some cols are optional?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

Say I have 5 varchar columns: str1, str2, str3, str4, str5

They are all covered by one index: (str1(10), str2(10), str3(10), str4(10), str5(10))

This index will work wonders for a query like:

`select count(*) from table where str1='foo' and str2='bar' and str3='baz' and str4='foo' and str5='bar'`

My question is simple - is there a way to structure a query to still use this index if the query doesn't include one of the middle columns? For example:

`select count(*) from table where str1='foo' and str2='bar' and str4='foo' and str5='bar'`

My first thought was to simply include `and str3 is not null` if I don't care about the value of str3, thinking that would still allow the index to be used, but explain seems to indicate that isn't the case.

Or is there an entirely better way to do this type of thing?

Comment: You should post along your example table data (with show create table syntax) and your query for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Using "prefixing" (that is, `(10)`) prevents "covering" because the characters after the first 10 are not in the index!

For `where str1='foo' and str2='bar' and str3='baz' and str4='foo' and str5='bar'`, `INDEX(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5)`, with the columns in *any* order, would be "covering".

However, if you have `VARCHAR(22222)`, it will spit at you because the index is "too big".  Even blindly using `VARCHAR(255)`, which a lot of novices do, may cause such an error.  So, shrink them down to 'reasonable' limits.  If it still says "too big", then you cannot make a covering index.

In this case, a subset of the 5 columns *may* be useful.  In this case, the optimization is not "covering" but "filtering".

If you sometimes leave out `str3`, then have `str3` *last* in the index definition.  This is because the *leftmost* columns of that index can still be used.

If, instead, you sometimes leave out a different column, then no single `INDEX` is optimal for all 3 cases.  I would suggest making an index starting with the columns you always use, then optionally tacking the others on the end.  Some will be covering, some won't.

Or you could have multiple indexes.  But this quickly becomes problematical if any combination of strings is optional.

Note:  This discussion (so far) *only* applies to testing for `=`.  In *general* if you use an inequality, it needs to be last in the index.  Having multiple "range" tests can be "covering", but not make effective use of the index otherwise.

`str3 IS NULL` optimizes like `=`, but `str3 IS NOT NULL` optimizes like a "range".

More discussion on building optimal indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql